# How to change the color of text in Navbar, when the Navbar is rendered in a different component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

First question on StackOverflow.

So, I have a Next App and the Navbar is being imported in the _app.js.

```
import Navbar from "../Components/Navbar";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Color or Navbar links is grey so when it is rendered on the most of the pages it works fine, as the BG is of light color. However, in some pages when navigated the color is not visible.

So, I want to know if there is a way to change the color of the Navbar links only when we are on that page. Like, for example when we visit the page :: http://localhost:3000/model3 , the color of the Navbar links should be white.
I am using the module approach on the Navbar and using sass as the CSS compiler with a Navbar.module.scss

**Model3.js**

```
    import React from "react";
    import section from "../styles/section.module.css";
    import S from "../styles/models.module.css";
    import E from "../styles/model3.module.css";
    import Link from "next/link";
    import Head from "next/head";
    import { Fade } from "react-reveal";

    function model3() {
      return (
        <div>
  <Head SameSite="None">
    <title>Model 3 | Tesla</title>
    <link
      rel="icon"
      href="https://www.tesla.com/themes/custom/tesla_frontend/assets/favicons/favicon.ico"
    />
  </Head>

  <div className={S.Wrapper}>
    <div className={S.Maincontainer}>
      <div className={S.Container}>
        <div className={E.TopSection}>
          <Fade bottom>
            <div className={section.carname}>
              <div className={section.title}>
                <h2 style={{ color: "white" }}>Model 3</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Fade>
          <Fade bottom>
            <div className={E.Details}>
              <div className={S.DetailsContainer}>
                <div className={S.DetailsHeading}>
                  <h3>3.1 s</h3>
                </div>
                <div className={S.DetailsData}>0-60 mph*</div>
              </div>
              <div className={S.DetailsContainer}>
                <div className={S.DetailsHeading}>
                  <h3>358 mi</h3>
                </div>
                <div className={S.DetailsData}>Range (EPA est.)</div>
              </div>
              <div className={S.DetailsContainer}>
                <div className={S.DetailsHeading}>
                  <h3>AWD</h3>
                </div>
                <div className={S.DetailsData}>Dual Motor</div>
              </div>
              <div className={S.DetailsContainer}>
                <Link href="">
                  <span>Order Now</span>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Fade>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>);}
    export default model3;
```

If there is anything that I should include please let me know. Thank you.

Please check at the top, all the Navlinks in the Navbar are grey, I need to change all of them to white when this page is rendered so that they will be visible

[The page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCaQG.png)

Comment: You're looking for active links. [Here is a tutorial](https://dev.to/yuridevat/how-to-add-styling-to-an-active-link-in-nextjs-593e).

Comment: I need all the Navlinks to change color from grey to white, not just the active one.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that:

- you can use your route hooks, React Router has useLocation(), you can verify the location and set a class to modify the behaviour based on the path.
- you can send a props to your navbar
- you can set a class to the body based on the route and then target your navabar with css `.dark .navbar`

The best method depends on the structure of your project